# Smali - injecting a simple method returns an Exception

Tags: java, android

I decompiled an APK and I'm adding an @Override onDestroy() method inside an Activity which doesn't have this method, and all that happens in Smali format and not in Java obviously. Yet I get an exception saying `java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.mobi.MainActivity due to bad method void com.mobi.MainActivity.onDestroy()`

I have tried creating a simple project in Android studio that has a simple onDestroy() method, Compiled it to an APK then decompiled the APK to get the Smali files, I went to MainActivity.smali and copied the onDestroy() codes and pasted it in the target MainActivity.smali to inject, I re-compiled it again and got the exception.

The simple onDestroy code I compiled and got the Smali from:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

    }
```

The Smali Code I got from this Method:

```
.method protected onDestroy()V
    .locals 0

    .line 49
    invoke-super {p0}, Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity;->onDestroy()V

    .line 51
    return-void
.end method
```

The Target Smali File After I pasted this code to it:

```
.method public onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
.... some code ...
.end method

.method protected onDestroy()V
    .locals 0

    .line 49
    invoke-super {p0}, Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity;->onDestroy()V

    .line 51
    return-void
.end method
```

It is Expected to Run smoothly without Any changes (because obviously the onDestroy() method has no instructions for now)

But I get This exception :

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.mobi.MainActivity due to bad method void com.mobi.MainActivity.onDestroy()
```

PS: When I re-compile the APK without the injected onDestroy code -> Works
PS2: When I recompile the simple app I created which has the same onDestroy() Smali code -> Works
PS3: When I re-compile the target APK with injected simple onDestroy() Smali Code -> Exception !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it ..

The problem is very clear, I'm posting this answer so it helps a lot of stuck devs out there:

The issue is in Line. 5

```
1. .method protected onDestroy()V
2.    .locals 0
3.
4.    .line 49
5.    invoke-super {p0}, Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity;->onDestroy()V
6.
7.    .line 51
8.    return-void
.end method
```

Where `Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity` is for Activities that extend `AppCompatActivity` as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
}
```

And `Landroid/app/Activity` is for Activities that extend `Activity` as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
}
```

The mistake I made is that I injected the `onDestroy()` method with it's `super.onDestroy()` in Smali without knowing if the target MainActivity.smali is `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity` .
In fact the target MainActivity was built upon `Activity` and the source MainActivity was made in `AppCompatActivity` , Thus the copied Smali code won't work on the Target MainActivity.smali like it did in the source activity.

Solution:

Change Line.5 from:

```
invoke-super {p0}, Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity;->onDestroy()V
```

To:

```
invoke-super {p0}, Landroid/app/Activity;->onDestroy()V
```

How to know if the target Activity extends `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity`? :
Just check the second line of the Activity's Smali file, something similar to:

```
1. .class public Lcom/mobi/MinActivity;
2. .super Landroid/app/Activity;
3. .source "MainActivity.java"
```

The second Line after `.super` shows the inheritance of the activity.

I Hope this may Help lot of people, and if you still didn't fall in this mistake, now you know how not to.